# What can I do to help boost engagement?

Tags: discussion

Your [roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/?cb=1) calls for efforts to increase community engagement.

What can I do, as a user, to help increase my engagement?  What message do you have for me?

I already visit Stack Overflow all the time, but I'd like to engage with the community more.  I'd like to take advantage of Stack Overflow features that I may not be aware of.  I'm cautious about privacy and disclosing personal information.  I enjoy editing and curating tasks, providing there continues to be some kind of recognition or achievements for such things.  I feel passionately about Stack Overflow's efforts to make the community more inclusive and friendly and to try to get everyone to have a positive experience.  I'm interested in sharing more information with my answers, such as creating better diagrams, videos or examples.  I love the surveys that you do and the information that you share.  (Is it weird that I like doing surveys?)  Although I enjoy moderating, I'm not interested in campaigning for diamond-level moderator privileges.  I think it's interesting how the various Stack Exchange sites relate and interoperate.  I love learning and teaching.  And I really like the idea of building my reputation within the community.  More than anything, I enjoy being helpful.

So how can I help?

Comment: Side note: "I enjoy editing and curating tasks" and "I'm not interested in moderating"? That is very confusing. Since editing and curating considered moderation are you saying you not interested in tasks you enjoy OR you consider editing not to be moderation OR something else altogether?

Comment: I interpreted as he's not interested in running for diamond janitor, @Alexei. In other words, the very narrow definition of the term "moderator", not the broad one where it means "curator".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I appreciate you drawing attention to that incongruity.  I had never read the complete list of diamond moderator responsibilities until reading Cody's message just now.  I admit I had assumed that I would never be able to earn the right to deal with users and their behaviour such as suspending users or dealing with complaints.  I assumed _moderator_ was the title reserved for the top level _diamond moderators_.  So Cody is right about what I meant.  It's the election process that turns me off.  Ironic since I'm asking about how to be more engaging.  Hmm...introspection time.

Comment: I edited to clarify what I meant about enjoying moderation, but not wanting to campaign for diamond-level moderator privileges.  Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [Why is SE wanting to increase engagement on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344216/165773)

Comment: "What can I do, as a user, to help increase my engagement?" Answer good questions with high quality answers. I try to, but the good questions are rare and often somebody else has already answered or answering them is actually pretty tough. Improve existing content. Vote. Curate. That's already a lot of work.

Comment: Being a diamond moderator is about a lot more than just curating content, so it definitely makes sense that someone like yourself would be interested in curating content but *not* interested in running for diamond moderator. Moderators spend a fair amount of time dealing with sockpuppets, plagiarism, abusive behavior, and other things far beyond content curation. Many of these are tedious; some are worse. It's a very important job, but even more important is having people out there actively engaged with asking/answering questions who are helping to make our content the best it can be.

Answer (score 23):

You’re overthinking it.

- Ask and/or answer questions: produce *exceptional* content.
- Edit others’ contributions to make *them* exceptional.
- Upvote exceptional content that you come across; downvote that which is not exceptional and/or fails to meet our commmunity standards. Push the most useful answers and most interesting questions to the top.
- Keep the site clean, well-organized, and useful to busy programmers by voting to close questions that are duplicates or off-topic, flagging answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, flagging spam, flagging noisy and/or rude comments. Use your eyes and ears; let a janitor know if someone ralphed on the floor so we can clean it up before anyone else trips over it.

Comment: Are users not disincentived to downvote? One loses reputation for doing so, do they not?  The reward here is that one must prioritize the good of the site over the reputation reward mechanism.  Downvoting seems to be treated like protesting or civil disobedience in that respect.  You know there will be a penalty but you do it anyway for the greater good.  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Wyck The penalty of downvoting is only on answers and quite low (at least if you have a couple of thousands of internet points and don't know how to spend them otherwise). It's just a small safeguard to avoid abuse of the feature. But downvoting should be as important as upvoting.

Comment: The idea is that you should cast your DVs wisely, rather than indiscriminately DV everything you see. Having a (trivial) rep penalty associated with DVs helps to reduce attempts to game the system, like DVing competing answers. Also worth noting that DVs on questions are "free", and any rep you lose from DVing answers that ultimately get deleted is returned to you when the answers are deleted. DVs are one of the most important tools you have as a content curator, so you should not shy away from using them. But yes, you are definitely doing it for the greater good, at a tiny loss to yourself.

Comment: Heh... I think I may have just reposted Trilarion's comment with twice as many words. Even had to compress all instances of "downvote" to fit around the character limit. Oh well.

Comment: I already do all those things; except I wouldn't self-describe my contributions as _exceptional_.  So either I'm not the target audience for boosting engagement, or Stack Overflow wants me to boost the quality of my contributions.  Judging by the comment "Working directly with targeted groups through UX research, we will identify and invest in features and tools that will improve the experience." does that mean that I am not part of those _targeted groups_? Otherwise it sounded like I was being asked for help--at least in the form of giving feedback on tools maybe or participating in UX study?

Answer (score 6):

> I enjoy editing and curating tasks, providing there continues to be some kind of recognition or achievements for such things.

Well, there are multiple review queues. You can spend **a lot** of time with that, and for each category, for your first 1000 items, there is one gold badge.

The trick here: avoiding to get into "robot" mode. Taking the time to *really* look at each item in the review queue, and processing it to the best of your knowledge.

And then, if you want to be "better" than the average reviewer: try to really understand each review queue. Not just by trial and error. You might find a lot of discussions about the queues here for example. And you can look at the queues, and see how *other* users reviewed entries. For example, when I worked "Help and Improvement", I actually came back with suggestions to triage reviewers who got their part really wrong.

Of course, the other key element here is: avoid going overboard.

> And I really like the idea of building my reputation within the community

It is good to be open about that. But keep in mind: in the end, the value of such reputation is very subjective. It first of all means: you spent a lot of time in this place, and you helped SE Inc. making real money, while all your gains are of a volatile, non-physical nature.

StackOverflow can make a nice hobby, that teaches you a lot. But it can also suck out a lot of time and energy. And it is just *one* variant of a social network. So learning how things work here doesn't necessarily give you big advantages in "other" places.