# What can I improve in my stats/profile if I want to nominate myself as moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators, candidate-score

I visit Stack Overflow almost on a daily basis, I really enjoy editing posts, making comments/asking questions and flagging questions, and of course providing answers so I have been thinking of nominating myself for moderator.

I know I'm missing the [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) badge, but what else is needed or recommended for my specific profile?

Someone mention that some of my stats seem a bit low for nominating, but they did not mention which ones.

I have checked some answers here on meta, but still I don't know what specific stats can be improved -
*[There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)*

Comment: If it's about candidate score specifically, then see [How is candidate score calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289501/how-is-candidate-score-calculated).

Comment: Maybe start by considering what about moderation you like.. editing? reviewing? investigating fraud? finding spam? "Not an Answers"? Something else?

Comment: Anyone know if we have a canonical Q&A here on Meta along the lines of "How can I get started with contributing to curation activities?" That would be the best duplicate, as participating in *user-level moderation* (which we often call "curation") is the best training for becoming a diamond moderator. I couldn't find one, but maybe someone wants to put their encyclopedic  knowledge of Meta up against mine?

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267839 and maybe even https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394236?

Comment: Come join us in the [election chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238039/2021-stack-overflow-moderator-election-chat), we have a bot that tells you what you're missing.

Comment: @cigien Thanks! Close, and useful, but not *quite* what I had in mind. Maybe we should think about creating one? I am thinking something very close to the "How does a new user get started on SO?" question, but focused less on a brand-new user and more on a user who's had an account for a while, but wants to start getting more into curation/moderation activities. codeMagic's answer to the first question comes the closest, but even more details and specific guidance would be great.