# Do I post inaccurate / incomplete / wrong questions?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement

I have posted a number of questions in the past few weeks.

When I post, I am usually very descriptive of the problem, or give enough details on the request if the topic is too broad. I also try to give details on solutions I tried.

I don't think I am posting about topics that no one attempted before, or topics that are so niche that only very few people could answer. In general, I think I post good questions, and I assume I should expect to receive at least some answers.

However, this is in complete contrast to the statistics of my questions. Other than a few which, either I found an answer myself, or someone posted a good answer, all my other questions get both a poor number of views and mostly no answers.

So I am asking here for help, from anyone willing to review my questions, to understand if I am posting wrong:

- Are my questions too short - or too long?
- Am I skipping important details, or adding too many details?
- Am I describing the problem (question) the wrong way, making people not understand my questions or misunderstand them for something else?
- Am I posting about topics that come up too frequently on Stack Overflow, and people are getting tired of answering the same topic over-and-over?
  *On this one, I admit that some questions I posted are about topics frequently discussed here on Stack Overflow. However, I am specifying the particularity of the situation, which makes previously answered questions not suitable for me, which consequently made me feel necessary to ask another question on the same subject.*
- Finally, any tips & tricks for improving my questions?

Thank you very much in advance to anyone willing to participate  this, be it with a simple comment, or a 10 page essay.

Comment: A quick note. When I looked at your [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A12186963+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0), you had 12. None had a score < 0, half had a > 0 score, and 3 a score of > 1. Only 1 was closed, as a duplicate, and that has a score of 2 as well. Just based on that alone, I'd say that your questions are in fact being quite well received.

Comment: About your last sentence, if you're referring to this meta question, then note that there are no bounties on MSO.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your feedback, much appreciated!
@ cigien I have noticed this, well, I hope to be able to give back somehow :)

Comment: @Larnu But 0 (or less) is taken as poor towards restrictions on posting questions.

Comment: @philipxy But can you say with the same amount of certainty when they start to count and how much? It's a secret. For all we know they only really start to count towards a ban when you have more downvoted questions than upvoted ones.

Comment: We aren't talking about a question ban here though, @philipxy . Though the algorithm for question bans treats 0 score questions as a contribution to them but (at least in my opinion) from a user perspective 0 score is different; 0 means that the question hasn't been negatively received either it's just a "meh" question. The fact the OP only has >0 scores on those unanswered qusetions means that they aren't at least being negatively received, and (like I also mentioned) several have multiple upvotes, which is a great indicator of a positive reception of said questions.

Comment: Javascript is a very busy tag. Regardless, having a question in any tag does not entitle you to an answer. If there were downvotes and close votes then that would be an indicator of a poor question but there's not much stopping people from glancing and moving on. It would be silly to ignore the gamification of this platform so if people are assessing effort/reward ratios I would say it takes a considerable effort to digest and properly answer your questions. Your questions seem to be very well written and formatted so I'd say you're Stack Overflowing properly.

Comment: I've edited out the mention of bounties, since that's not possible on MSO. I'm very glad to hear that you would like to give back somehow. Here's an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394238) listing some ways you can do that.

Comment: In general your question quality is way above average, but I see a couple of issues: (1) Completely eliminate the chat (e.g. _"...this may be a dumb question"_,  _"What do you guys think?"_). Fluff makes your questions longer, and less likely to be read. (2) Some of your questions are very broad, and contain multiple related questions. Just before posting, check whether you are asking more than one question. If so, then ask yourself whether it might be better to post multiple shorter questions. TLDR: Make your questions crisper, and more focused.

Comment: If you are worried that your questions (or your answers too) are too detailed, you can choose to post a TL;DR version at the start and then the detailed version. I often do that if I feel that the question or answer (or any communication in general) is becoming too long to read.

Comment: @cigien thank you! Also thanks to skomisa, anishsane and everyone else for tips! I may start to use TL;DR, they seem like a good idea and maybe i can reduce the whole answer to the TLDR version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll be honest, I've only looked over one of your questions. Sorry. I'll throw in my thoughts anyway though.

The fact that you've asked this question (and the comments which others have are left on it) indicate that you are probably not asking poor quality questions. Anyone putting in enough effort to bother asking on meta how to improve their questions is already thinking along the right lines by simply caring about question quality.

I would suggest that the 'problem' is not that you are asking poor questions, but simply that all the low hanging fruit is already gone. If a question is of interest to a large number people, there are good odds that someone has already asked it. If it's never been asked in the history of stack overflow, then probably not many people are interested in it. It stands to reason that you'll come across questions with really high engagement, but it's important to recognise that they're not average questions. The reason you have come across them (often years after they were asked) is because they are the (very few) questions which genuinely have lasting appeal to many people. Most questions are much more specific, and likely to only appeal to a relatively small proportion of visitors. That's not a bad thing, and they are still helpful to the people who do have an interest in them.

I realise I'm painting with very broad brushstrokes here, and there will be plenty of exceptions (i.e. good questions which are yet to be asked). On the whole though, I think your experience is normal. You ask questions, a few people vote on them, some get answered, and hopefully on balance the whole process is a net gain to you. Asking a question which receives a large number of upvotes or numerous correct answers is a fairly rare occurrence, it's just a very visible one because those are the questions we're more likely to stumble across while searching for solutions to our problems.

Comment: Also, if you take a look at the [average question score among some of the top tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1182894/top-langs-vs-haskell-rust-average-question-score) you'll see that it's commonly *below* 0. So even merely in terms of question score, 0-score Qs are above average.

Comment: Just another fun fact to learn about this website, haha

Comment: Thank you, Tim, i think your answer is the most complete explanation i could get. Makes sense too. At least i have confirmation on my methodology :)